# How to capture frame-by-frame images from iPhone video recording in real time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avcapturesession

I am trying to measure the saturation of a selected color in real-time, like this:

[image: Idea]

I am following [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1702/_index.html) from Apple. I updated the code to work with ARC, and of course made my view controller an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`, but I don't know how to actually start capturing the data, as in starting up the camera to get some actual input.

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

    [self setupCaptureSession];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Create the session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Configure the session to produce lower resolution video frames, if your
    // processing algorithm can cope. We'll specify medium quality for the
    // chosen device.
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    // Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice
                               defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                        error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handling the error appropriately.
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];

    // Configure your output.
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

    // Specify the pixel format
    output.videoSettings =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                                forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];


    // Start the session running to start the flow of data
    [self startCapturingWithSession:session];

    // Assign session to an ivar.
    [self setSession:session];
}

- (void)startCapturingWithSession: (AVCaptureSession *) captureSession
{
    //----- DISPLAY THE PREVIEW LAYER -----
    //Display it full screen under out view controller existing controls
    NSLog(@"Display the preview layer");
    CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
    [self.previewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
    [self.previewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                          CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
    //[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self CaptureManager] self.previewLayer]];
    //We use this instead so it goes on a layer behind our UI controls (avoids us having to manually bring each control to the front):
    UIView *CameraView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [[self view] addSubview:CameraView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:CameraView];

    [[CameraView layer] addSublayer:self.previewLayer];


    //----- START THE CAPTURE SESSION RUNNING -----
    [captureSession startRunning];
}

// Delegate routine that is called when a sample buffer was written
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}

// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This did it for me, it was all about setting up a video preview:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

    [self setupCaptureSession];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Create the session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Configure the session to produce lower resolution video frames, if your
    // processing algorithm can cope. We'll specify medium quality for the
    // chosen device.
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    // Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice
                               defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                        error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handling the error appropriately.
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];

    // Configure your output.
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

    // Specify the pixel format
    output.videoSettings =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                                forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];


    // Start the session running to start the flow of data
    [self startCapturingWithSession:session];

    // Assign session to an ivar.
    [self setSession:session];
}

- (void)startCapturingWithSession: (AVCaptureSession *) captureSession
{
    NSLog(@"Adding video preview layer");
    [self setPreviewLayer:[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession]];

    [self.previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];


    //----- DISPLAY THE PREVIEW LAYER -----
    //Display it full screen under out view controller existing controls
    NSLog(@"Display the preview layer");
    CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
    [self.previewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
    [self.previewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                          CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
    //[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self CaptureManager] self.previewLayer]];
    //We use this instead so it goes on a layer behind our UI controls (avoids us having to manually bring each control to the front):
    UIView *CameraView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [[self view] addSubview:CameraView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:CameraView];

    [[CameraView layer] addSublayer:self.previewLayer];


    //----- START THE CAPTURE SESSION RUNNING -----
    [captureSession startRunning];
}

// Delegate routine that is called when a sample buffer was written
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
    [connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}

// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you provide the example project ? tks

Comment: @MackC Sorry. I lost some old files--this along with it.

Comment: I am getting a warning on line `[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];` that says `Sending 'ViewController *const__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>'` Any ideas why this warning occurs?

Comment: @EthanAllen Does your ViewController conform to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`?