# Video Frame from camera using AVFoundation Framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, video-processing

I never worked with AVFoundation Framework, I want to get video frames from the back camera and process with these frames. Any one to help me, your experience will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: process means? what do you want to do?

Comment: Further i want to match with Template:  naresh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882605/how-to-capture-frame-by-frame-images-from-iphone-video-recording-in-real-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code to start camera session with AVFoundation in order to capture a still image:

```
AVCaptureSession *session;
AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;

session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];

if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
    [session addInput:deviceInput];
}

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
CGRect frame = self.frameForCapture.frame;
[previewLayer setFrame:frame];
[rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

[session startRunning];
```

Then, in order to actually capture the image, you can use a button with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                  completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
                                                          NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                                                      }
                                                  }];
}
```

Then, you can do whatever you want to do with the saved image.